# how to force service starts after network is ready in Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, debian

I'm setting up a nginx proxy server in the network, in the nginx conf file it looks for upstream servers through hostnames; the server uses dhcp interface.

every time reboot, nginx always fail to start, i ran into init 1 then invoke init 3, i can see that nginx fail because it can't find upstream servers, as network is not ready. when the interface is ready ,i start nginx /etc/init.d/nginx start , all works just fine.

I used debian before, debian starts networking during boot, won't continue booting until network is ready or timeout(dhcp), there won't be such problems.

I wonder how to make ubuntu works the debian way, make the networking ready before other server starts.

Comment: Belongs on http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed a similar problem by putting a simple script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`.

Try putting this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

give it a name you like and make the script executable. It should be executed each time network is ready.